# Why do we use bitwise operators & and ~ instead of mathematical operators % when implementing aligned malloc?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

When studying about Memory Management of the Linux operating system, I see that the general solution to implement the aligned malloc function is the following code:

```
void *aligned_malloc(size_t required_bytes, size_t alignment) {
    void *p1; // original block
    void **p2; // aligned block
    int offset = alignment - 1 + sizeof(void *);
    if ((p1 = (void *)malloc(required_bytes + offset)) == NULL) {
       return NULL;
    }
    p2 = (void **)(((size_t)(p1) + offset) & ~(alignment - 1));
    p2[-1] = p1;
    return p2;
}
```

This solution has a problem that is it only works properly when the `alignment` is a power of 2 due to the `& ~(alignment - 1)`. Moreover, `alignment` has to be a `size_t` data type so that it would fit the data type of pointer `p1`.
Because of these limitations, I've thought of another solution that is:

```
void *aligned_malloc(size_t required_bytes, size_t alignment) {
    void *p1; // original block
    void **p2; // aligned block
    int offset = alignment - 1 + sizeof(void *);
    if ((p1 = (void*)malloc(required_bytes + offset)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    offset = (size_t)(p1) % alignment; // offset is used so that I don't have to declare another variable
    p2 = (void **)((size_t)(p1) + (alignment - offset));
    p2[-1] = p1;
    return p2;
}
```

This solution solves both problems, that is `alignment` doesn't have to be neither a power of 2 nor `size_t` data type. My question is that, why isn't this way of implementing the aligned malloc used? What are its drawbacks that make people choose the solution with the bitwise operators `&` and `~` instead?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For starters, your code doesn't leave space for a `void *` at `p2[-1]` like the original code did.  In your code, `p2[-1]` may be outside the block returned by `malloc`, which is bad.

Comment: Also note that allowing `alignment` to be a non-power of 2 is not really useful, because the usual reason to want to align a memory block is for CPU operations that are more efficient (or only allowed) on aligned data, and those are invariably power of 2 requirements.  So nobody is ever going to want a block aligned to a multiple of 3 or 5 or 13, and thus there's no reason to make the code less efficient to support that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that the classic code has problems, but not exactly those mentioned:

- `alignment` must indeed be a power of 2, which is a constraint for the POSIX standard function `aligned_alloc`. In fact `alignment` must be a power of 2 greater than or equal to `sizeof(size_t)` and the size argument should be a multiple of `alignment` under this standard.
- `alignment` is defined with type `size_t`, but this bears no connection to the data type of pointer `p1`. As a matter of fact, `size_t` and `void *` might have a different size as was the case in 16-bit MSDOS/Windows middle and large model architectures.

  Hence the code `p2 = (void **)(((size_t)(p1) + offset) & ~(alignment - 1));` is not strictly conforming. To fix this problem, one would use `uintptr_t` defined in `<stdint.h>` which is specified as having the same size as `void *`:

  ```
    p2 = (void **)(void *)(((uintptr_t)(p1) + offset) & ~(alignment - 1));
  ```
- there is another problem in the posted code: if `alignment` is smaller than `sizeof(void *)`, `p2` might be misaligned for writing `void *` value `p1`. Extra code is needed to make sure `alignment` is at least as large as `sizeof(void *)`. In real systems, this is not a problem because `malloc()` must return pointers that are properly aligned for all basic types, including `void *`.

The reason bitwise `&` and `~` operators are preferred is one of efficiency: for `x` an unsigned integer and `alignment` a power of 2 `x & (alignment - 1)` is equivalent to `x % alignment`, but it is much faster for most CPUs to compute with a bitwise mask than with a division and the compiler cannot make the assumption that `alignment` is a power of 2 so it would compile you code using the much slower integer division instruction.

Furthermore, your computation is incorrect: if `p1` is misaligned, `offset` (computed as `(size_t)(p1) % alignment`) can be as large as `alignment - 1`, so `p2` can be as close to `p1` as 1 byte, so `p2[-1] = p1;` would write before the beginning of the allocated space.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment) {
    // alignment must be a power of 2
    //assert(alignment != 0 && (alignment & (alignment - 1)) == 0);
    void *p1;     // allocated block
    void **p2;    // aligned block
    size_t slack; // amount of extra memory to allocate to ensure proper alignment
                  // and space to save the original pointer returned by malloc.
    //compute max(alignment - 1, sizeof(void*) - 1) without testing:
    size_t alignment_mask = (alignment - 1) | (sizeof(void *) - 1);
    slack = alignment_mask + sizeof(void *);
    if ((p1 = malloc(size + slack)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    p2 = (void **)(void *)(((uintptr_t)p1 + slack) & ~alignment_mask);
    p2[-1] = p1;
    return p2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because `alignment` is a variable with a (for the compiler) unknown value, which means that the compiler can't easily it as a simpler operation.

Bitwise operations are simpler and more efficient than the arithmetic (especially division) needed by the `%` operator.

Comment: `alignment` is a variable in the original version as well. (I do agree with the second paragraph.)

Comment: Also, old-school programmers have the habit of simply avoiding `/` and `%` for performance reasons, and to write the code with respective shift/mask if applicable. If the compiler can do the conversion itself, it won't hurt performance if the programmer has already done the same thing, and if the compile can't, well then the programmer produced faster code. This concrete example is one of the cases where the compiler can't (because it does not know the alignment value), and where the reflex of using bit operations does pay off.

Comment: So my second solution is right and just not as efficient as using the `&` and `~` operator right? Because I am not sure if it is wrong (in some circumtances or some other computer architectures) or it is just not efficient.